# Как установить RubyInstaller и Compass на сервер через SSH?

Tags: ruby, ssh, sass

Как я могу с помощью SSH установить на сервер RubyInstaller и в дальнейшем Compass?

Comment: Какая ОС на сервере?

Comment: ОС на сервере Линкус

Comment: @kl09, линуксов существует тьма тьмущая с разными менеджерами пакетов. Выполните в консоли команду `uname -a` и покажите нам вывод.

Comment: Linux server54.hosting.reg.ru 2.6.32-431.20.5.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jul 25 08:34:44 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

RubyInstaller он, как-бы, для Винды, а у вас Линукс.
Воспользуйтесь [RVM](https://rvm.io/)
или [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)